# Stacked Negative/Positive Time Series Using ggplot2 and geom_area

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I'm trying to reproduce a stacked time-series graph which shows how the composition and size of a bank's balance sheet changes over time. It should look something like this:

[image: Balance Sheet]

Where assets go above the x-axis and liabilities go below it.

So far I've been able to reproduce each half of the graph successfully using `ggplot()`:

```
# plot assets stack
assets.plot <- ggplot(assetsm, aes(x=dates, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_area() 


# plot liability stack
liabiln.plot <- ggplot(liabilnm, aes(x=dates, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_area()
```

which gives:

[image: Assets (left) and liabilities (right)]

But when I add them together, something goes wrong:

```
# plot whole bs
bs.plot <- ggplot(bsm, aes(x=dates, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_area()
```

which gives:

[image]

Taking note of the colour scale beside it and the picture above, you can see that:

1. Only half the variables are shown (from V19 onwards).
2. These variables happen to coincide just with the 'liabilities' half of the data (which are all supposed to be negative numbers).
3. The total height of the stack at each point on x is equal to the total height of the liabilities stack in the graph above, but it no longer starts at y=0 - it lands on both sides of the y-axis.

I have no idea what's missing from my code to cause this - I've fiddled around with making `position = "stack"` explicit, as well as trying the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439632/combined-positive-and-negative-stacked-line-plots) (same result), and I'm now at my wit's end.

I think this might be a data problem, so I've uploaded the data [here](https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B2bdLsnOAbZHUVJvem1XbXdScDA/edit). If I can make the question clearer or give extra details, let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't quite explain the behavior you're seeing at the moment, but when I do top/bottom type plots like these, I tend to use separate data frames an separate layer calls:

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_area(data = assetsm, aes(x=dates, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
    geom_area(data = liabilnm, aes(x=dates, y=value, fill=variable))
```

which seems to look like what you're after:

[image]

Comment: that worked first time, thank you. Is it really just using separate data frames that made the difference?

Comment: @steve I think (but I'm not 100% sure) that the issue has to do with how ggplot knows how to do the stacking, which is a harder problem than you might think, from the perspective of writing plotting functions that should magically anticipate a wide range of user input.