# ggplot2 positive/negative plot not rendering cleanly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to replicate a top bottom plot like the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732421/stacked-negative-positive-time-series-using-ggplot2-and-geom-area) but it's not rendering correctly (the purple series has +ve and -ve values and the green is negative) leaving messy artifacts. I'm also struggling to create a toy example which replicates the issue so I'm hoping that someone can help despite my lack of data

my code is:

```
negatives <- result[result$value < 0,]
positives <- result[result$value >= 0,]

ggplot() + 
  geom_area(data = negatives, aes(x = datetime, y = value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_area(data = positives, aes(x = datetime, y = value, fill=variable))
```

The structure of my data is:

```
dput(droplevels(head(result)))

structure(
list(
    datetime = structure(c(1421751900, 1421751900, 1421752200, 1421752200, 1421752500, 1421752500), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    variable = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("V-S-MNSP1", "VIC1-NSW1"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(9, 80.106180098, 9, 77.719632578, 9, 84.158868934 )
), 
.Names = c("datetime", "variable", "value"), 
row.names = c(NA, 6L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

[image: top/bottom plot]

Comment: Can you make this reproducible? Maybe simulate some sample data?

Comment: Hi @Gregor, no sorry that's my problem - it only occurs with my real data set. All my attempts so far to reproduce with toy data have failed...

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect anyone to help you with it in that case... You can also share the smallest sample of your data you can find that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Yes I understand, I was hoping that someone has seen this before and had some ideas. I'll try and subset the data until I manage to reproduce

Comment: It looks a bit like bad variable classes. At the very least, post `dput(droplevels(head(result)))` and we can tell if your data appears to have good structure.

Comment: Please format it and edit it into your question.

Comment: Hi @Gregor, I've done that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, my data points can be positive or negative. It appears that the stacking doesn't work if I don't have a value for each variable for each datetime. So instead of doing this

```
negatives <- result[result$value < 0,]
positives <- result[result$value >= 0,]
```

I do this

```
result$positive <- ifelse(result$value >= 0,result$value,0)
result$negative <- ifelse(result$value < 0,result$value,0)

ggplot(data = result) + 
  geom_area(aes(x = datetime, y = positive, fill=variable), position = 'stack') +
  geom_area(aes(x = datetime, y = negative, fill=variable), position = 'stack')
```

And my chart then renders correctly

Dave